# Использовать системный размер шрифта

Tags: android

Я выставляю свой размер шрифта в dimens.xml.

Мне нужно, что бы изначально системный размер шрифта (установленный в настройках телефона). 
И в каком значении мне потом выставлять размер шрифта? (dp, in, mm, pt, px, sp)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен системный размер, то в dimens.xml размер шрифта указывать не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Размеры шрифтов задаются в `sp`. Стандартный размер записан в стиле `TextAppearance` (обычно это `14sp`), который используется примерно так:

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body"
```

Подробнее можно посмотреть в [гугловских гайдлайнах](https://material.io/design/typography/#typography-standard-styles)